# awk - using a regex statement (with slashes) inside action (braces)

Tags: awk, gawk

Using:

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

I'm somewhat puzzled by the proper use of regex enclosed in forward slashes `/` inside  action braces `{ }` in `awk`. For instance, this works:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '/test/ {print $0}'
4,testing
```

Using `if` and `match`, instead of the forward slash regex syntax, also works (provided additional outer action braces are added):

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '{if(match($0, "test")) {print $0}}'
4,testing
```

So, I guess, `/REGEX/` should be equivalent to `if(match($0, "test"))`, right?

Anyways, I want to do some testing per field - and then a regex check on the entire string... and `match` within nested action braces from `if` works as expected:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '{if($1==4) {if(match($0, "test")) {print $0}}}'
4,testing
```

... but then, if I want to replace the `if(match(...))` with a forward slash regex, I get:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '{if($1==4) {/test/ {print $0}}}'
awk: {if($1==4) {/test/ {print $0}}}
awk:                    ^ syntax error
```

Can anyone explain what the rules are, when to use forward slash regex - and when to use `match()` regex?

---

While writing this, I discovered by accident that this works:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '{if($1==4) {if(/test/) {print $0}}}'
4,testing
```

... so it seems: within an action, the forward slash regex must be in an argument of an `if` statement... But that still doesn't make sense to me - given that in the very first example above, the regex is *not* (at least, not in a manner obvious to me) located in an `if()` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string inside forward slashes is a *regex string* in `awk` like  `/test/` not an operation just like the `match()` function is a function and not an operation. The syntax `/test/{print $0}` is short hand `if ($0~/test/){print $0}` where `~` is the regexp comparison operator. This is when the condition is outside the block however.

You are equivalating `{if (match($0, "test")){print $0}}` with `{/test/{print $0}}` however you still need to the `if` statement when inside a block:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '{if($1==4) {if (/test/){print $0}}}'
4,testing
```

The regexp operator `~` is what is commonly used not the `match()` function although it does has it's usecases.

What you really should be doing is:

```
$ echo "4,testing" | awk -F, '$1==4&&/test/'
4,testing
```

We don't need a block as the default block in `awk` is `{print $0}` and the we use the logical operator AND to test for both conditions being TRUE using `&&`.

Comment: Fantastic explanation, @sudo_O - especially the part about shorthand explained me a lot. Apologies for the late accept - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The basic syntax of `awk` is that it's a sequence of:

```
<condition> <action>
```

The `<condition>` is an expression that's tested on each line; if it's true, the `<action>` is executed. If action is a `{ ... }` block, it must contain *statements*. In a statement, to test a condition you have to use `if`.

Another way to think of it is that there's an implicit `if` around the `<condition>` part of each `awk` line.

A regexp is just a type of expression that can appear in a condition.

Comment: Thanks for that @Barmar - sorry for the late response! I usually trip on such a general semantic explanation (like in this case) - but the part about the "implicit `if`" helps; however, I think the detailed pinpoint of my mistakes by @sudo_O deserves the accept. Cheers!